# Opening form submit result in a new tab in Eclipse-RCP intro page

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have developed an eclipse RCP product, in which the first intro page has a form (xhtml).
On submitting the form, the result page appears in the same tab. I want the result page to be opened in a new tab. I tried using target="_new" and also target="_blank" in the form element tag.

```
<form name="application" action="http://example.com" method="post" target="_new">
```

But the result page is opened in a new internet explorer window and not within the eclipse RCP application.
Please help me with a solution.

-Dinesh

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. This widget is just an embedded Internet Explorer there is no interaction with any other controls.

A possible workaround would be to collect your formdata via javascript, create a new eclipse command with a parameter (where you store your collected formdata as String), which is executed when you submit the form (see the documentation how to call commands from the welcome-screen) which opens a new Browser Window in Eclipse and navigates to the action-page with the formdata as query (which would be the same as a form with GET method)

Comment: In the intro page im using the form with method as "post". I am sending a big chunk of data as http request. So navigating to the action-page with the form data as a GET method is tedious and will restrict the payload length. 
Is there any other workaround or solution?

Comment: You could post your data via AJAX, so that the page is not reloaded, after you have received the AJAX response you can use the mechanisms I've described above (just collecting the AJAX result and appending it as query to show a suitable result-page)